# Does Xamarin Forms support base application resources?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have an application that will be lightly customised for different tenants (Mainly service layer and light UI changes) so i have designed a core project with a base Application class that tenant projects have to inherit from. Said base application class has an associated Application XAML with some implicit application-wide styles but it seems the app does not pick them up as the controls render with completely native styling.

Is it really not supported or am i doing something wrong here?

This is the XAML

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  xmlns:branding="clr-namespace:AT.UI.Common.Branding;assembly=AT.UI.Common"
    x:Class="AT.UI.Common.BaseATApplication">

  <!-- TODO: Find out how to make this work for subclasses -->
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
          <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{x:Static branding:UIBranding.StandbyButtonBackgroundColor}" />
          <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{x:Static branding:UIBranding.ButtonForegroundColor}" />
        </Style>
      </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

BaseATApplication's constructor has the required InitializeComponent() call.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that they need to be explicitly referenced

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
          <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{x:Static branding:UIBranding.StandbyButtonBackgroundColor}" />
          <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{x:Static branding:UIBranding.ButtonForegroundColor}" />
</Style>

<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
```

Comment: I'll try but it should pick them up as implicit but i might have hit a bug similar to https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=27659. Good catch